# How to get second @entitie.literal when I have two or more "same" entitity on same phrase

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

For example, my input text are:

You can I talk with someone

on entity I have:

@pron:aboutme = I, Me
@pron:aboutother = someone, anyone, everyone, Richard

So... I want get @pron:aboutother literal

The problem is @pron.literal returns "I" and not "someone"

How can get @pron:aboutother input literal for this case?

Comment: Have you checked how many entities are returned?

Answer (score 0):

`@sys-number` is a shorthand syntax. In this case, you need to use full syntax `<?entities['pron'].get(1).literal?>` to get the literal of the second detected entity. It might be good to check if there are two entities of the type detected in the input before (otherwise you get arrayoutofbounds exception).